# Пример кода с использованием формальных параметров в UNIX

Tags: unix

Напишите, пожалуйста, простой пример с использованием формальных параметров в unix. Я никак не пойму, как это правильно написать. В МС-ДОС например можно написать код в ***.bat*** файле, и потом просто запустить его и все дела. А в UNIX какая здесь система? Как я вроде понял, это надо писать в функции, ну а как это вообще писать? В каком файле? Напишите простой пример, как создать 2 файла и потом их удалить, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ vim test.sh#!/bin/bashtouch $1echo "Файл $1 создан"touch $2echo "Файл $2 создан"rm $1echo "Файл $1 удален"rm $2echo "Файл $2 удален"$ chmod +x test.sh$ ./test.sh one twoФайл one созданФайл two созданФайл one удаленФайл two удален
```

Здесь $1 и $2 - параметры командной строки, принимаемые скриптом. По сути, простейший сценарий bash - набор команд, выполняемых оболочкой, touch и rm - внешние программы.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, ты мне очень помог!